# Proper syntax for try statement, if previous statement errors, do this

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to use a control-of-flow statement in a stored procedure that says:

```
begin try
 sql_statement
end try
begin try
 sql statement
end try
begin catch
 print error
end catch
```

But the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql) on try catch says:

> A TRY block must be immediately followed by an associated CATCH block.
>   Including any other statements between the END TRY and BEGIN CATCH
>   statements generates a syntax error.

What would the proper syntax for this be in sql:

```
execute x_sql_statement
if x_sql_statement errors
execute y_sql_statement
else end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the above if you're beginning a `TRY`, ending it, and then starting another `TRY`. The error message is literally telling you the problem here:

> A TRY block must be immediately followed by an associated CATCH block

Maybe do something like this...?

```
DECLARE @Error bit = 0;

BEGIN TRY
    execute x_sql_statement;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @Error = 1;
    execute y_sql_statement;
END CATCH

IF @Error = 0 BEGIN
    execute z_sql_statement;
END
```

But then, why not do...

```
BEGIN TRY
    execute x_sql_statement;
    execute z_sql_statement;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    execute y_sql_statement;
END CATCH
```

Unless you don't want statement `y` to run if `z` fails?

Answer (score 1):

Typically something like this

```
begin try

    execute x_sql_statement

end try
begin catch

    execute y_sql_statement

end catch
```